# DateTime->Format functions unexpectedly with % symbol

Tags: php, datetime

I am currently auditing a codebase to transfer to a PHP 7 installation. One of the issues we are seeing is with DateTime->format(), where an argument string gets passed in with a percent sign precluding a value, and in this circumstance, any comparison operator treats it as a string, not as a numeric value

```
$dto = new \DateTime('now');
if($dto->format("%y") == 20) {
```

> PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/application/models/User.php on line 225

Has there been a change between PHP 5 and 7 in regards to using the Percent sign in format() statements? Or am I missing something here? It is only a Warning statement, but I would rather keep the error log clear of anything that could take up space.

Comment: I think you're thinking the `DateInterval` formatting, which takes `%` -- the formatting for `DateTime` and just `date()` does not.

Comment: `DateTime::format` returns string and you try to compare it to a number.

Comment: Maybe use `==` instead of `=` ???

Comment: What are you expecting `->format(''%y")` to return? If you just want the year, do: `->format('y')`. I've never used `%` in PHP's format (not even on PHP 5). Here's [the manual about formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: [`DateTime::format()` has never taken `%` before formatting characters since its introduction in 5.2.0.](https://3v4l.org/U2Rr4) This would seem to indicate that the original code never worked.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you can use literals in the format, right? So `%y` would result in string `%19` for example.

Comment: @Dharman Yes, of course, sorry, I thought that much was obvious. Clearly that's why the check is failing, it's comparing `%19` to `19`.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking against an integer in your if statements which leads us to the assumption that the `%` sign in your format is not required.
While it is not forbidden to include literals such as `%` in your format string it doesn't have any semantic value, it is just treated as ordinary percent character. This means that the result of your `format()` would be for example `'%19'`, which is a non numerical string and cannot be compared to an integer. Your if statement will always fail.

If the result you expected was `'19'`, a numerical string, then you can just remove the `%` from the format string.

```
$dto = new \DateTime('now');
if($dto->format("y") == 20) {
```